# What are the differences between a wiki and a CMS

Tags: content-management-system, comparison, wiki

What are the differences between a wiki and a CMS?  Is there any?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**CMS:**

1. A CMS focuses on **content** which is then published through standardized templates -- think of an online newspaper as driven by a huge CMS system.
2. It's about standardized **publishing information**.
3. CMS'es usually have a **limited group** of editors.
4. Useful for **relatively static** content, maintained by non-tech people.
5. **Much emphasis on style**/presentation: very slick templates so it looks professional.

**Wiki:**

1. On the other hand, a wiki focuses on **pages** where each page represents a topic.
2. It's much more about **collaboratively improving each topic** (adding hyperlinks to other topics and websites counts as improving the topic).
3. Wikis are generally **much more open to "the public"** (or everybody in the company, vs. just the "internal communication" department).
4. Wikis are *meant* to be **living, dynamic things,** maintained by *everybody*.
5. Much **emphasis on content:** less slick templates but easier to find and update information.

Comment: It's a simple explanation... focus on "?What's the problem ?Whats the solution... (c)"... have my vote,,, thx Torben!

Answer (score 13):

The difference is in the letter "M". A content management system *manages* content. A CMS often has built-in workflow and other features to make it easier to manage a collection of assets. For example, to move articles from staging to production, to facilitate proofreading, etc.

A wiki is more like a public bulletin board. Anyone can add any content at any time and in any way they choose.

Think of it perhaps as the difference between an IDE and a text editor. Both can be used for many similar tasks but one is a bit more structured than the other.

Of course, the lines can blurr in that some Wikis have tools for managing the content and some CMS's are nothing more than "type here and press the submit button".

Answer (score 8):

Typically a Wiki is community editable, visitors to the site can edit it, take Wikipedia for example.  A CMS is more designed typially, for a set of site administrators to manage and display content.

Answer (score 5):

A Wiki is a type of CMS, CMS come in many flavors, but all manage some content somehow.  In a wiki's case the content is user-editable and creatable information or articles.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, a wiki is built on a CMS.  A wiki is an application, that people use.  A CMS is just a kind of database.  CMS's often have front-end administrator applications.  However, the point of a CMS is to manage content for some purpose-built front-end application.

CMS is to Wiki as Database is to Financial Application.

Answer (score 1):

In the conceptual world a Wiki is for collectible content, anybody can create, delete, modify any content. Is oriented on knowledge.

A CMS manages content, is oriented on format, form, maintenability.

Some wikis are constructed with an CMS

Answer (score 0):

A CMS is a **Content Management System**. The idea behind the development of CMS evolved when the need for a Management System amplified. A CMS works as a cornerstone for web development by the help of which a developer can build powerful and feature-rich websites in minimum amount of time and effort. A good and powerful CMS not rectifies the frustrating need of writing repetitive and mundane codes, but also eliminates arduous and heavy tasks involved in building a website or web application.

Wikipedia on the other hand is an **information directory**. Sites such as Wikipedia can be built on a CMS, for instance `The New York Times` and `TechCrunch` is built on `WordPress`. In regard to information acquisition, Wikipedia is the best place that a user can go for - even better than Google. The number of articles Wikipedia contains is stupendous and highly reliable. The daily number of users depending on Wikipedia for information, itself serves as a testimonial for the service Wiki offers to us users.